# android service startForeGround functionality

Tags: android, android-service, background-service

is Calling startForeGround mandatory to make a service background service?
When I start a service and return START_STICKY on onstartCommand function,it will start again after service kill.(example close app with swiping)
I could not understand functionality of startForeGround function.returning START_STICKY is not enough?

Answer (score 1):

`startForeGround` is no needed if you are going to run a `background service`, this method is useful when you you want to run a `foreground service` which probably will show a Notification while it is running. This is a nice way to make a service run for a long time even if the user killed(closed) the app.

Comment: thank you so much :) but I found that it is needed if service started with  startForegroundService (for oreo and later versions) .is it true?

Comment: yes, but as I told you, That is for running `foreground services`. check the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)